# What (aside from the law) prevents cloud-hosting owners from eavesdropping on servers/code?

Tags: web-application, privacy, webserver, databases, cloud-computing

Given a server hosted on a cloud platform, what would stop the cloud platform owner from stealing the server's data and/or code?

As far as I can tell, a motivated cloud owner could retrieve the data in its servers while keeping plausible deniability.

Certain large companies also seem to have incentive to do this, as they'd benefit from extra data.

Comment: Their reputation.

Comment: @Jeroen There are situations in which data-harvesting could be done discreetly enough that their clients don't realize it. For example, how would a client know if their customers' names and addresses are being harvested?

Comment: @Asker they don't know that. If you use someone else's computer to store your data, you better trust them!

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you cannot protect a system against its administrator. So when a company hosts a site or an application in an external computer center, they **trust** that computer center to behave professionally.

For that reason, it in common not to externalize the most sensitive informations.

As usual when it comes to Information Security, everything ends as a matter of cost and risk. For rather trivial information, the gain of externalization is higher than the risk of stealth, but for highly sensitive information the risk is often bigger than the gain.